# Calculate missing vector based on the angle I'm supposed to get

Tags: matrices, vectors, coordinate-systems, angle, complex-multiplication

Let's say I have a vector (-1,2,-3) and I want to combine this with an other vector, so the angle of these 2 vectors would come out to 30°. How would I go about calculating this?
My professor showed us an example for this kind of task but didn't really go into the specifics, just the theory, so I know I have to somehow use the dot product? Not sure how exactly though.

I hope I've managed to explain this well enough, English isn't my first language.
Thank you for every answer that could steer me into the right direction with this task.

Comment: What do you mean by “to combine”?

Comment: Well the vectors are going to be connected and the angle of the 2 vectors should come out to a 30° angle

Comment: @gamer42069 there will be an entire cone of such vectors and you'll need to use that $\frac{a \cdot b} { \vert a \vert \vert b \vert} = \cos (\theta )$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how I'd do it though I don't know if it's how your professor means.

1. take the cross product of this vector with some other vector, preferably a unit vector in one axis to make your life easier. (in other dimensions, you can use the gram-schmidt process instead but that's harder to explain)

$$ v = (-1, 2, -3) \times (1,0,0) = (0,-3,-2) $$

This vector is known to be perpendicular to your input vector.

2. scale both of these  vectors to unit vectors, so they have known lengths.

$$\begin {align}
\hat u &= \frac{u}{|u|}=\frac{(-1,2,-3)}{\sqrt{14}}\\
\hat v &= \frac{v}{|v|}=\frac{(0,-3,-2)}{\sqrt{13}}
\end{align}$$

3. add them together using the sine and cosine of the desired angle to get the final result

$$\begin{align}
\hat q &= \hat u \cos\theta + \hat v \sin\theta\\
&= \frac{(-1,2,-3)}{\sqrt{14}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{(0,-3,-2)}{\sqrt{13}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{3}{56}}(-1,2,-3)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{52}}(0,-3,-2)
\end{align}$$

Which is a miserable enough pile of numbers that I'm not going to do the addition out, but it *is* a unit vector and it is indeed $30^\circ$ away from the input vector.